# JQuery UIDatePicker - Setting Max Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, uidatepicker

I am trying to set the max date for the uidatepicker in my html page using jQuery. I have tried the following:

```
   $(function() {
      var theDate = new Date();
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
          {
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
          maxDate: new Date(theDate.getYear(), theDate.getMonth(), theDate.getDate());
      }
      );
```

This doesn't work....What am I doing wrong? I want to make it so the date picker has a max date of today's date...

Comment: Have you tried `maxDate` instead of `minDate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `;` at the end of the `maxDate: ...` line that shouldn't be there. Looks like it would result in a syntax error.

Does your browser's error console tell you there's a JavaScript error of some kind?

Comment: Ok, so the semicolon was causing a problem. but now in the uidatepicker it displays the year wrong (instead of 2011 I get 111)

Comment: Ok I got it. I needed to replace getYear with getFullYear